# php - how to store variable value into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

hey guys i am a newbie in php therefore i need you help. as the title says i am trying to store variable value into database table.

this is my php code that i wrote however it doesn't seem to be working. it doesn't seem to be storing any values in the database.

```
<?php
    // to connect to database 
    require("user_connection.php");

    $query = "INSERT INTO booked (date, computer_id, name, start_time, end_time) VALUES ('$date', '$select3', '$username', '$select1', '$select2')";

    mysqli_query($query);       
?>
```

can you please help me check if there is anything wrong with my code. the database table is called "booked" and the columns are "date, computer_id, name, start_time, end_time". below is the full code of the page

```
<?php

    // starts a session and checks if the user is logged in
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];


    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();

    }   

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>



                        <!-- heading -->
        <div id="intro">Thankyou for booking a slot using the booking system.</div>


                        <!-- echo out information -->

        <div id="fonts">

        <h4>Below is the information of your booking:</h4>

            </br>
            </br>

        <b>Student Name:</b> <?php echo $username; // echo's name ?>
            </br>
            </br>



        <b>Room No:</b> <?php $room = $_SESSION['g'];

                echo $room; // echo's room ?>
            </br>
            </br>



        <b>Computer No:</b> <?php 

                $select3 = $_POST['bike'];
                echo  $select3;
                ?>
            </br>
            </br>



        <b>Date:</b> <?php $date = $_POST['datepicker']; 
                echo $date; // echo's date 
                ?>
        </br>
        </br>



        <b>Start Session and End Session:</b> <?php 
                if(isset($_POST['select1']) && isset($_POST['select2'])) {
                $select1 = $_POST['select1'];
                $select2 = $_POST['select2'];
                echo $select1;
                echo "";
                echo $select2;
                }
                else{
                echo "not set";
                }
                ?>

        </div>





        <?php

            // to connect to database 
            require("user_connection.php");

            $query = "INSERT INTO booked (date, computer_id, name, start_time, end_time) VALUES ('$date', '$select3', '$username', '$select1', '$select2')";

            mysqli_query($query);


        ?>






    </body>


    <footer>
        <p>Copyright © 2016 MyComputer &nbsp; | &nbsp; Contact information: <a href="mailto:gurungmadan@hotmail.com">gurungmadan@hotmail.com</a></p>
    </footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about “don't working”? Surely you perform the query even when nothing is submitted. You have to move the query inside previous `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend you to use PDO insteand of mysqli. You can see more informations about why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189).

With the pdo way, your code would result with something like this :

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO booked (date, computer_id, name, start_time, end_time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $data = array($date, $select3, $username, $select1 ,$select2);
    $sth = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute($data);
```

By using the prepare statement, you're protected from sql injections.